Textures imported and mapped to MeshBasicMaterial appear considerably lighter than they should
I have a tile engine that imports a tilesheet and then creates tiles to display them, but they appear much lighter and are somehow being altered. I’ve not changed the initial variables of the scene or renderer. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's how they look side-by-side.
I've had the same results with other tilesheets, the materials are all much lighter than their images.
